# Proving that Compact Implies Seperable in a Metric Space

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a Compact Metric Space.

We wish to show that X is Seperable.

Given $ \delta = 1/n \;$ , $\bigcup_{x\in X} D(x,1/n) \; $ is an Open Cover of X

Since X is Compact $ \exists $ Finite Subcover , $\bigcup_{x\in E_n} D(x,1/n) \; $

Since each $E_n$ has finitely many points, Consider $$ S = \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty}E_n $$

Is this proof ok? I mean S is obviously countable but is the density part fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it looks correct.

$S$, a countable union of finite sets, is countable.

$S$ is dense: Choose a $x \in X$. If $x \in S$ then we're done.

Otherwise take $r > 0$. For any neighborhood $N(x, r)$ we have that $x$ is contained in a neighborhood centered around $p$ of radius $\frac{1}{N}$, with $N$ chosen large enough such that $\frac{1}{N} < r$. So $N(x, r)$ contains a point of $S$ for any $r$, so $x$ is a limit point of $X$ and thus $S$ is dense in $X$.